# @font-face not displaying on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I am currently using the bulletproof syntax and converted fonts from Font-Squirrel for the fonts on 
www.runningwithpurpose.org.nz (fonts inline css in the html - working)
www.runningwithpurpose.org.nz/broken (fonts in css file - not working)
.
The both methods display fontes fine on browsers other than IE which sometimes will display some or all the fonts and other times not at all (but usually not at all). 
I have tried playing around with the htaccess file, using the 'smiley' syntax but neither worked. 
However I did manage to fix it but putting the font css inline in the html file.
This is ok but I was wondering why I seem to be unable to get it working as many other people have the @font-face declarations in the css file which would be much cleaner and it used to work fine for me but doesn't.

Any suggestions on how to get this working would be great, considering no other existing help has worked.

One of the @font-face declarations used

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller-Regular';
    src: url('assets/fonts/aller-regular.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/aller-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/aller-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/aller-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('assets/fonts/aller-regular.svg#Aller-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare font-face in your css file? It is important to declare it before any other css.

Comment: At the bottom, putting it at the top didn't help/change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my question I was able to fix it at the time by putting the @font-face declarations inline in the html. 
But now IE seems to have decided to fix itself and let me declare @font-faces in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Google webfont instead ?, I used to used fontface but found that Google font are a million times easier to implement, plus the user doesn't have to download the font off your server each time, it just comes straight from Google.
http://www.google.com/webfonts